# Nodeunit - JSCovrage

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage, nodeunit, jscoverage

Is there a way to use JSCoverage to have code coverage for nodeunit?

I know there is [`nodeunit2`](https://npmjs.org/package/nodeunit2), but my code is not in lib, and I do not want to restructure my project.

Answer (score 1):

Sure... Just follow the steps in [this example](http://www.vapidspace.com/coding/2014/01/31/code-coverage-metrics-with-nodeunit/).

The key elements being:

1. run the `jscoverage` command on the directory (or directories) that house your code
2. Provide some mechanism (such as an environment variable) to make a choice when you include your module to include the correct version of your code
3. When you want code coverage statistics, set your environment variable accordingly